# Change the highlight color on a JetBrains Theme

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm, clion, jetbrains-ide

I want to change the color that a theme has when you highlight characters and when you want to check for indentations.

An image of the highlighting color that isn't readable:

[image]

Another image:

[image]

I have the color theme `.icls` open but changing "Selection_Background" doesn't resolve all the highlighting issues.